# Access the Real URL for JSONP request in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, authentication, jsonp, cors, interceptor

Here's the basic setup for a JSONP call using `$http`'s JSONP function

```
var authenticatedUrl = authenticateUrl("http://example.com/getStuff&callback=JSON_CALLBACK");
return $http.jsonp(authenticatedUrl).then(function (response) {
  ...
}
```

The problem is, my HMAC authenticator is creating a hash based on the url with `callback=JSON_CALLBACK`, then by the time angular makes the actual request, the URL changes to have `angular.callbacks._0` as the callback param, which makes my authentication hash invalid.

**How do I access the real url that will be used for this JSONP request?**

From my research, it appears that interceptors is the way to go with this, but I can't seem to find an object with the URL that has the `angular.callbacks._0` callback.

Comment: dumb question but what does `authenticate the url` mean?

Comment: @charlietfl - HMAC authentication. it generates a hash string based on the URL and a secret key.

Comment: @charlietfl - I edited the question to clarify what i really want (the real request URL).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are using something like [Hawk - Single URI Authentication](https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk#single-uri-authorization); this is you get a token that you have to attach to the url and the token is valid for that exact url.

The problem you have, it is not angular per-se but the way that every jsonp framework is supposed to work.

I will suggest forking [JSONP](https://github.com/LearnBoost/jsonp) to add this behavior or doing JSONP manually.

```
var i = 0;
function call_endpoint(callback) {
    i++;
    var url = "http://example.com/getStuff&callback=callback_" + i;

    //append the token here, or call your endpoints to fetch the endpoint.

    window["callback_" + i] = function (data) {
      delete window["callback_" + i]; 
      callback(data);
    };

    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;

    var target = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0] || document.head;
    target.parentNode.insertBefore(script, target);
}
```

Comment: I feel like there should should be something that exposes the "transformed" url (the one with the `angular.callbacks._0`). I'm thinking something similar to in jquery's ajax, there's a "beforeSend" option where I can access the url. Because that transformed url is not exposed (that I can find), there's no way to do create a proper authentication token.